# Does gspread.open only support English file name?

Tags: gspread, google-colaboratory

I used the Importing data from Google Sheets code snippet. It works fine with my files in English.
Then, I tried some Chinese file names, and file name with characters like é, ê. It throws error saying SpreadsheetNotFound. I am sure I have files with those names in my Google Drive.

Does gspread.open only support English file name?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this only happens on Python2 notebooks.